# how to approachlayout of related git repositories

Tags: git

Lets say I have some starter javascript kit project with all of my tooling setup.  Lets say I want to create another project that is the original tarter kit plus angular tooling. And lets say there is a 3rd starter kit that is the "plain" kit, plus angular, plus MongoDB.  Are these 3 separate repositories with multiple common files just duplicated?  Or is there something more clever that I can do?  Pardon the analogy, but I guess I am asking for inheritance at the repository level.... I want 3 starter kits where each kit is the superset of the previous one.  Clear?  Thanks.   I guess I dont mind having 3 separate copies of files, but it would suck to fix the same bug in 3 separate places.

Answer (score 0):

You can "link in" other git repos as submodules:

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules

So you have 3 gits but 2 of them reference others. From what I heard it makes commits to submodules and pushes/merges/updates to submodule origin branches interesting - but you only have to change code around once and then pull/push/merge it. If you develop alone and don't use feature requests etc it should be easier.

Answer (score 0):

I have done some reading and it sounds like git basic fork functionality is exactly what I need -- a separate project that is based on some other original project, and its not a copy.  Whats more, when the original project gets changed, I can update the "derived" project with changes.  Sounds great, but it seems github does not allow you to fork your own repositories. What a bummer.